# At what portion of the game will Brute Splicers stop appearing?

Tags: bioshock-2

The ["Research Camera" article](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Camera#Strategy_2) at the BioShock wiki states:

> Brute Splicers stop appearing for a portion of the game, although they re-appear near the end, so it is important to research them sooner rather than later.

I would like to make sure to fully research Brute Splicers before they stop appearing (as they'll only appear again near the end of the game).

**At what portion of the game will Brute Splicers stop appearing?** (Before they re-appear near the end of the game.)

Note: Can't find any info about this at the ["Brute Splicer" article](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Brute_Splicer) at the BioShock wiki.

Comment: Forget Brute Splicers - the Spider Splicers disappearing is a much bigger problem. Researching them is the only way to get the very useful final "fast-movement" tonic, but they stop appearing about half way through the game and *don't come back near the end*. I was stuck walking slowly the whole game.

Comment: @MGOwen You might want to ask another question about that. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I failed to finish researching Brute Splicers by a few points, before they stopped appearing.

**From my experience, they stop appearing at [Dionysus Park](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Dionysus_Park)** (the sixth level). So make sure to fully research them before leaving [Siren Alley](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Siren_Alley) (the fifth level), if you want to get the [research rewards](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Research_Rewards#Brute_Splicer), including the [Armored Shell 2](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Armored_Shell) gene tonic at an earlier part of the game.

They will re-appear again near the end of the game (at the final levels, [Outer Persephone](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Persephone) and [Inner Persephone](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Inner_Persephone)).

Source: Personal experience, and from verifying it at the [walkthrough guides at GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/945381-bioshock-2/faqs). The walkthrough guides don't mention Brute Splicers appearing at Dionysus Park, and mentioning them appearing again near the end, at Persephone.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can remember from my game, the Brutes stop spawning when you reach

> [Fontaine Futuristics](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Fontaine_Futuristics_%28Level%29)

and start respawning (huge loads of them) at the very last level of the game, so you better complete the research before you reach that level!

I'm sorry I could not provide a valid linkable source for this, but there seems to be none around except [forums where people posts their gameplay experience](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=208615)

Comment: Could you link to those forum posts? [From my personal experience and from reading some walkthrough guides, Brute Splicers stop appearing at Dionysus Park](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102624/4797), which is an earlier level than Fontaine Futuristics.

Comment: Edited and added one of them as a link :)